# Copy a folder recursively in Azure App Service (Windows) is extremely SLOW

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi I've tried to copy a whole folder which has 311 JPGs inside to another one in Azure App Service (Windows), the speed is extremely slow, which took 20.8sec to finish!!! The same PHP scripts had been put to Amazon EC2 and it took 0.34sec to finish.

[image]
[image]

It's just 311 files. Did anyone have such the experience before and any tips can help, or file operations in Windows Server is normally slow so please give it up....

Thank you very much~

I have also pasted the code what I did (testing code):

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$filesystem = new Filesystem();
try {
    $src = __DIR__ . '/../uploads/2021';
    $dest = __DIR__ . '/../uploads/2021b';
    $filesystem->mirror($src, $dest);
} catch (IOExceptionInterface $exception) {
    echo "An error occurred while creating your directory at ".$exception->getPath();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your recent post and asked a lot of questions. After reading all the questions, I think there is no problem with your needs, but there are problems with your ideas and concepts to solve the problem.

Regarding this post, you are talking about copying speed. First of all, `azure web app` is a `PaaS` service, and `Amazon EC2` is a `laaS` service. The two are not comparable. Of course, `Amazon EC2` processes files faster. This is not a problem at all.

And `Azure Web App Service` is used to deploy web services, but programmers pay more attention to code development and monitoring web applications, rather than specifically for file storage, copy management and other management. There can be static file resources in the project. Generally, the file size in a project is not too large, so the capacity of `D:/` in the `S1 plan` is only `5 GB`. These capacities are allocated to the service plan, and a service plan can also be used by many app services.

Generally, azure web app files are recommended to be stored using azure storage, which is very fast, and file storage will not be unavailable due to program upgrades (change of programming language and other factors).

Comment: Thank you for your advise which is very clear. I am going to take a look at Azure storage.